# QML Peformance on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: c++, qt, qml, raspberry-pi3, jit

I've installed Qt5.7 from repository in my rasp. After compiling my qml program I'm getting following messages and my qml is too slow:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
inotify_add_watch("/home/pi/.config/qt5ct") failed: "No such file or directory"
```

I've also enabled the openGL driver and also added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mthumb-interwork -mthumb -march=armv7` flags to the .pro, but didn't help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to enable the [Qt Quick Compiler](http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/).

> The Qt Quick Compiler is a development add-on for Qt Quick applications which allows you to compile QML source code into the final binary.

You can try a recent version of Qt, according to the official docs:

> Since Qt version 5.11, the functionality of the Qt Quick Compiler has been integrated into the Qt Quick module itself. This separate add-on remains available in the earlier long term support releases of Qt.

If you still want to use the same version, just add to your qmake configuration file:

```
CONFIG += qtquickcompiler
```

You also need to add the compiler flags, as mentioned on the wiki page:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mthumb -mthumb-interwork
```

Finally, enable the proper driver by following these steps:

1. Open raspi-config
2. Go to Advanced Options
3. Go to GL Driver
4. Enable GL(Full KMS)