# Run Qml application on raspberry pi

Tags: qt, qml

I have compiled the qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.8 on raspberry pi3 successfully. But when I run the qml application in raspberry,I am getting error message like,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/testqml $ ./testqml -platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb0

JIT is disabled for QML. Property bindings and animations will be very slow. Visit https://wiki.qt.io/V4 to learn about possible solutions for your platform.
This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlagsQSurfaceFormat::FormatOption(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DoubleBuffer), swapInterval 1, profile QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
Aborted
```

I already tried this link "[QML Peformance on Raspberry Pi 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319846/qml-peformance-on-raspberry-pi-3)" ,but same problem happened.

Comment: Are you trying to run the application on a minimal installation of raspbian or do you run it with a desktop on it?